# How to make a vote system in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a website.
I have made a post and a user model.
I want every user to vote for every post.(Up OR Down)

I think I need a new model. How do I make one?
It should save votes for every user and post.
And I want a post.ranking, which is the sum of all up and down's.

Post

```
model.py

class Post(models.Model):
...
ranking = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

User

```
model.py

class UserZ(authmodels.User, authmodels.PermissionsMixin):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/avatar', null=True, blank=True, default='/static/img/Weramemesicon.png')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: why not save the voting information in the `Post` model??

Comment: No Problem just tell me how.

Comment: First, look out there. It's a common thing to do, so [maybe someone else did this already](https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote)

Comment: sry but i think i dont need an extra application for it. i just need a few lines of code.

Comment: I would definitely go for reusing existing code

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel. You could use [`django-vote` app](https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote)

**Install `django-vote` by pip**

`pip install django-vote`

**Add `'vote'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting like this**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'vote',
)
```

**Add `VoteModel` to the model you want to vote**

```
from vote.models import VoteModel

class ArticleReview(VoteModel, models.Model):
    ...
```

**Run migrate**

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

**Use vote API**

```
review = ArticleReview.objects.get(pk=1)

# Up vote to the object
review.votes.up(user_id)

# Down vote to the object
review.votes.down(user_id)

# Removes a vote from the object
review.votes.delete(user_id)

# Check if the user already voted the object
review.votes.exists(user_id)

# Returns the number of votes for the object
review.votes.count()

# Returns a list of users who voted and their voting date
review.votes.user_ids()


# Returns all instances voted by user
Review.votes.all(user_id)
```

Comment: okay i pip installed it? Where i put: class ArticleReview(VoteModel, models.Model):

Comment: You need to add `VoteModel` to the model you want to use. As in you need to add `VoteModel` to the `Post` model. As in you need to write this: `class Post(VoteModel, models.Model):` instead of what you already have: `class Post(models.Model):`

Comment: Ok and where and how do i call all the functions?

Comment: This is a whole different question, that I don't have time to answer. You're practically asking how python and django works :)

Comment: @SaschaWick you could called the functions the view where the user is supposed to vote.